# What should the value of Windows.Current.Content be after opening a secondary window?

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

This is the suggested code in the App class from the Template10 article on [implementing a shell](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Controls#implementing-a-shell):

```
public override Task OnInitializeAsync(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    var nav = NavigationServiceFactory(BackButton.Attach, ExistingContent.Include);
    Window.Current.Content = new Views.Shell(nav);
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

The new shell object is assigned to Windows.Current.Content.

This is the suggested code for opening a secondary window (not with a shell), from [the Template10 Secondary window example code:](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/version_1.1.13p/Samples/MultipleViews/ViewModels)

```
 var control = await NavigationService.OpenAsync(typeof(MySecondaryPage), null, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());  

                control.Released += Control_Released;
```

What is the relationship between Windows.Current.Content and the secondary window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the relationship between Windows.Current.Content and the secondary window?

Actually, The [`NavigationService.OpenAsync`](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/8f5491cda806f1f39eee923b97df1afaaf27413e/Template10/Template10.Core.Windowing/View%20(TODO)/ViewService.cs#L28) method internally invoke [`ViewService.OpenAsync`](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/8f5491cda806f1f39eee923b97df1afaaf27413e/Template10/Template10.Core.Windowing/View%20(TODO)/ViewService.cs#L28).

```
public async Task<IViewLifetimeControl> OpenAsync(UIElement content, string title = null,
    ViewSizePreference size = ViewSizePreference.UseHalf)
{
    this.Log($"Frame: {content}, Title: {title}, Size: {size}");

    var currentView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    title = title ?? currentView.Title;

    var newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
    var dispatcher = DispatcherEx.Create(newView.Dispatcher);
    var newControl = await dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
    {
        var control = ViewLifetimeControl.GetForCurrentView();
        var newWindow = Window.Current;
        var newAppView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
        newAppView.Title = title;

        // TODO: (Jerry)
        // control.NavigationService = nav;

        newWindow.Content = content;
        newWindow.Activate();

        await ApplicationViewSwitcher
            .TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newAppView.Id, ViewSizePreference.Default, currentView.Id, size);
        return control;
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return newControl;
}
```

From the above code, you could get the app's `Window`(Singleton) has not been changed, when the second window activated, the `Content` of `Window` was replaced with second page. And when the previous window activated the `Windows.Current.Content` will turn the fist page back. And you could verify this with `Window.Current.Activated` event.

```
Window.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;

private void Current_Activated(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
{
 // check the sender
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers the question exactly.