# How to open a secondary window with a shell?

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

I tried to adapt the instructions for implementing a shell in Template10 [on GitHub](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Controls#implementing-a-shell) to a shell in a secondary window, but it is not working.

This code:

```
await DispatcherWrapper.Current().DispatchAsync(async () =>
        {
                //The next line gets the exception
                var control = await BootStrapper.Current.NavigationService.OpenAsync(
                                                    typeof(MySecondaryShell), null, "My Secondary Function");
                control.Released += Control_Released;
                BootStrapper.Current.NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(MySecondaryPage));
    });
```

gets this exception:

> E VUI 1808 16:12:27.203  D:\SVN_Trunk\Source\Uwp\Gui\UwpMain\ViewModels\MyPrimaryShellViewModel.cs.275.MyFunction
>       System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>       at Uwp.Main.UwpMain_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
>       at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType, Object parameter, NavigationTransitionInfo infoOverride)
>       at Template10.Services.NavigationService.FrameFacade.Navigate(Type page, Object parameter, NavigationTransitionInfo infoOverride)
>       at Template10.Services.NavigationService.NavigationService.d__34.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Template10.Services.NavigationService.NavigationService.Navigate(Type page, Object parameter, NavigationTransitionInfo infoOverride)
>       at Template10.Services.ViewService.ViewService.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at Template10.Services.ViewService.ViewService.d__1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>       at Uwp.Main.ViewModels.MyPrimaryShellViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass63_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()

MySecondaryShell is constructed like this:

```
public static HamburgerMenu HamburgerMenu => Instance.EmulatorHamburgerMenu;

    public MySecondaryShell(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        HamburgerMenu.NavigationService = navigationService;
    }
```

When I open the primary window with its shell, I create the shell object and then assign the NavigationService to it.

But when I'm opening a secondary window, I just call NavigationService.OpenAsync with the typeof(MySecondaryShell) as a parameter.  Is the problem that the NavigationService is not set correctly in the shell? (From reading the Template10 code in [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698947/what-should-the-value-of-windows-current-content-be-after-opening-a-secondary-wi), I could not see where the NavigationService is set).

How should I open a shell as a secondary window?

Comment: Do you have any updates?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT hi, sorry yes - thank you for this great answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I open a shell as a secondary window?

The problem is you have not passed navigationService to `MySecondaryShell`. And then `MySecondaryShell` will fail initialization without navigationService. You could make your shell like following.

```
public sealed partial class MyShell : Page
{
    public static MyShell Instance { get; set; }

    public static HamburgerMenu HamburgerMenu => Instance.MyHamburgerMenu;

    Services.SettingsServices.SettingsService _settings;
    public MyShell()
    {
        Instance = this;
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _settings = Services.SettingsServices.SettingsService.Instance;
        var service = BootStrapper.Current.NavigationServiceFactory(BootStrapper.BackButton.Attach, BootStrapper.ExistingContent.Exclude);          
        SetNavigationService(service);

    }  
    public void SetNavigationService(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        MyHamburgerMenu.NavigationService = navigationService;
        HamburgerMenu.RefreshStyles(_settings.AppTheme, true);
        HamburgerMenu.IsFullScreen = _settings.IsFullScreen;
        HamburgerMenu.HamburgerButtonVisibility = _settings.ShowHamburgerButton ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
await DispatcherWrapper.Current().DispatchAsync(async () =>
{
    var control = await BootStrapper.Current.NavigationService.OpenAsync(typeof(Views.MyShell), null, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    await control.CoreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        Views.MyShell.HamburgerMenu.NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.TestPage));
    });

});
```